# PHP Get HTTP Response Code

Tags: php, http

I have found a way to get the HTTP response code from a URL using `get_headers($url)`. This function returns an array like the following...

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:13 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
    [3] => Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
    [4] => ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
    [5] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
    [6] => Content-Length: 438
    [7] => Connection: close
    [8] => Content-Type: text/html
)
```

My problem is that I may have a large list of URLs that I want to loop though and get the HTTP response code for each URL. It seems like a nasty and slow way to use this function inside a loop for potentially 100's of URLs.

How can I speed up this process and make it cleaner or is this the best way to do it? I would love to know your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just wanting the http response codes or the entire details of the response?

Comment: Have you actually profiled it and found it to be slow?

Comment: Just the response codes, I know I could do something like `foreach($urls as $url) echo get_headers($url)[0]; }`. I am wondering is there is anything faster?

Comment: @itsliamoco "Faster" does *not mean anything* unless you can show us how slow it is, and tell us how fast you need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

The network calls inherently take time, but you can get to completion faster by running those calls in parallel. One way to do that is to use curl_multi. Give me a minute and I'll write out an example.

```
//set up list of urls and arrays to hold responses
$urls = array(
    'http://www.livestrong.com/',
    'http://www.apple.com/'
    //add more urls here
);

$response_map = array();
$responses_by_url = array();

//create the multi object
$multi = curl_multi_init();
foreach($urls as $url) {
    //add a request for each url
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $response_map[$ch] = $url;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    //since that's all you need, we'll save some bandwidth by just asking for the HEAD
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');
    curl_multi_add_handle($multi, $ch);
}

//start the multi request
$still_running = 0;
curl_multi_exec($multi, $still_running);

//loop while waiting for completion
do {
    curl_multi_select($multi); //blocks until state change
    curl_multi_exec($multi, $still_running); //get new state

    //read all available new information
    while ($info = curl_multi_info_read($multi)) {
        if ($info['msg'] === CURLMSG_DONE) {
            //we're done, check the result
            if ($info['result'] === CURLE_OK) {
                //result ok, parse it
                $url = $response_map[$info['handle']];
                $header_text = curl_multi_getcontent($info['handle']);
                curl_multi_remove_handle($multi, $info['handle']);
                $header_array = explode("\r\n", trim($header_text));
                $responses_by_url[$url] = $header_array;
            } else {
                //record error
                $responses_by_url[$url] = "error: " . curl_error($ch);
            }
        }
    }
} while ($still_running);

//clean up
curl_multi_close($multi);

//output results
var_dump($responses_by_url);
```

Comment: cURL Multi **does not** make requests in parallel, it makes them asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [curl_multi_init()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) to perform these 100 requests faster. There is a small php lib [php-multi-curl](https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl) which can help you do the task.